# BERT model : "enable_padding() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_length'"

Tags: nlp, padding, tokenize, bert-language-model

I am trying to implement the BERT model architecture using Hugging Face and KERAS. I am learning this from the Kaggle ([link](https://www.kaggle.com/tanulsingh077/deep-learning-for-nlp-zero-to-transformers-bert)) and try to understand it. When I tokenized my data, I face some problems and get an error message. The error msg is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-888a40c0160b> in <module>
----> 1 x_train = fast_encode(train1.comment_text.astype(str), fast_tokenizer, maxlen=MAX_LEN)
      2 x_valid = fast_encode(valid.comment_text.astype(str), fast_tokenizer, maxlen=MAX_LEN)
      3 x_test = fast_encode(test.content.astype(str), fast_tokenizer, maxlen=MAX_LEN )
      4 y_train = train1.toxic.values
      5 y_valid = valid.toxic.values

<ipython-input-8-de591bf0a0b9> in fast_encode(texts, tokenizer, chunk_size, maxlen)
      4     """
      5     tokenizer.enable_truncation(max_length=maxlen)
----> 6     tokenizer.enable_padding(max_length=maxlen)
      7     all_ids = []
      8 

TypeError: enable_padding() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_length'
```

and the code is:

```
x_train = fast_encode(train1.comment_text.astype(str), fast_tokenizer, maxlen=192)
x_valid = fast_encode(valid.comment_text.astype(str), fast_tokenizer, maxlen=192)
x_test = fast_encode(test.content.astype(str), fast_tokenizer, maxlen=192 )
y_train = train1.toxic.values
y_valid = valid.toxic.values
```

and the function fast_encode is here:

```
def fast_encode(texts, tokenizer, chunk_size=256, maxlen=512):
    """
    Encoder for encoding the text into sequence of integers for BERT Input
    """
    tokenizer.enable_truncation(max_length=maxlen)
    tokenizer.enable_padding(max_length=maxlen)
    all_ids = []
    
    for i in tqdm(range(0, len(texts), chunk_size)):
        text_chunk = texts[i:i+chunk_size].tolist()
        encs = tokenizer.encode_batch(text_chunk)
        all_ids.extend([enc.ids for enc in encs])
    
    return np.array(all_ids)
```

What should I do now?

Comment: `fast_encode` doesn't seem to be from hugging_face.

Comment: I am learning this from the Kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/tanulsingh077/deep-learning-for-nlp-zero-to-transformers-bert) and I am not sure about this.

Answer (score 2):

The tokenizer used here is not the regular tokenizer, but the fast tokenizer provided by an older version of the Huggingface `tokenizer` library.

If you wish to create the fast tokenizer using the older version of huggingface `transformers` from the notebook, you can do this:

```py
from tokenizers import BertWordPieceTokenizer

# First load the real tokenizer
tokenizer = transformers.DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-multilingual-cased')
# Save the loaded tokenizer locally
tokenizer.save_pretrained('.')
# Reload it with the huggingface tokenizers library
fast_tokenizer = BertWordPieceTokenizer('vocab.txt', lowercase=False)
fast_tokenizer
```

However, the process of using a fast tokenizer has become significantly simpler since I wrote this code. If you look at the [Proprocessing data tutorial](https://huggingface.co/transformers/master/preprocessing.html) by Huggingface, you will notice that you simply need to do:

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')

batch_sentences = [
    "Hello world",
    "Some slightly longer sentence to trigger padding"
]
batch = tokenizer(batch_sentences, padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors="tf")
```

This is because the fast tokenizer (which is written in Rust) is automatically used whenever it's available.

Answer (score 1):

Use length instead of max_length in the enable_pedding function.

Current: `tokenizer.enable_padding(max_length=maxlen)`

Change to : `tokenizer.enable_padding(length=maxlen)`

This will work.